# C++ - Character array output remove loop error

Tags: c++, c++11

I wish to make a function to remove a character array output, one at a time. The character array is pre-defined, but there is a problem.

```
void anim_rev(char str[])
{
    clrscr();
    int i;

    for(i = 1; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        cout << "\b \b";
        delay(25);
    }
}
```

The `cout` statement is being executed first for all the iterations, and then the `delay` is executed. The function is supposed to remove a character from the screen every 10 or 25 milliseconds.

Please help fix it.

Comment: Can you please be more precise in your question? We kind of need to guess what you need to do. And please, don't say the loop logic is correct when you ask the community to tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Why not just "\b \b" at once? Can you add more context? How do you run it? What is the expected output and what it actually outputs?

Comment: @Sirmyself The first statement in the block is executed first, and this actually removes all the text at once, and then executed the `delay` is executed, which is not what I need.

Comment: @Ayxan There were a few different versions before coming to this one, and still the error. It is run inside the main() function. and it is supposed to remove one character from the output screen every 10 or 25 milliseconds

Comment: And why do you clear screen with `clrscr()` before removing characters? Would there still be something to remove?

Answer (score 0):

`std::cout` use a buffer and usually it flushes the buffer when there is a `std::endl`.

If you force the `flush` of `std::cout` it should work.

Here the documentation of how to flush with an example:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/flush

Comment: I use C++ 11 for coding, and it does not `std::cout`

Comment: @DarshK what? `std::cout` is part of the C++ language since 1998!

Comment: @Simon please format your code, e.g. put variables and other programming related terms (e.g. `std::cout`) in backticks (`\``)

Comment: I know but I also use Turbo C++ IDE, which is kind of ancient, and does not support `std::cout`. Learnt that the hard way.

Comment: @DarshK Turbo C++ does not support any C++. Not C++11, not C++98, not any.  It uses the long extinct non-standard C++ variant from 1992.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, note the `flush` in the end of each `cout`.

Otherwise it will be written only at the end of line, or at the end of program.

note: `delay` is not standard function so I used `sleep` instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <Windows.h>  
#define sleep(X) Sleep(X*1000)  
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
using namespace std;


void anim_rev(const char str[])
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        cout << "\b" << " " << "\b"<<flush;
        sleep(1);
    }
} 
int main(void) 
{
    const char* p="Helooooooo";  
    cout<<p<<flush;
    anim_rev(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `delay()` can be used when you include `dos.h`

Comment: @DarshK Most of IDEs doesn't support it. anyway you should add the `flush`

Comment: The code does not completely work for multi line array strings.

Comment: @DarshK Correct, printing `\b` works only for the current line. it won't cancel the line feed.

Comment: Then how do I cancel the line feed?

Comment: @DarshK if you work in dos, you can use `gotoxy` from `conio.h`

Comment: Is there a way to count the number of lines in the string?

Comment: Please contact me on facebook or messenger as Darsh Kumar at: [link](https://www.facebook.com/darsh.kumar.75)

Comment: @DarshK You can use `wherex`, `wherey` (also from `conio.h`) if you do `y1=wherey()` then print and again `y2=wherey()` `y2-y1` will tell you how much lines were printed.